# Conversion from Option<&str> to Option<String>

Tags: rust

What is the best practice to convert `Option<&str>` to `Option<String>`? Strictly speaking I'm looking for a concise equivalent of:

```rust
if s.is_some() {
    Some(s.to_string())
} else {
    None
}
```

and this is the best I could come up with:

```rust
s.and_then(|s| Some(s.to_string()))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) is a better choice:

```
s.map(|s| s.to_string())
```

or

```
s.map(str::to_string)
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to use `s.map(str::to_string)`:

```
let reference: Option<&str> = Some("whatever");
let owned: Option<String> = reference.map(str::to_string);
```

I personally find it cleaner without the extra closure.